# Asterisk - как переадресовать входящие c usb-модема на внутрений номер?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Модем настроил, ussd, sms и исходящие с него совершаются.
Не могу понять как настроить входящие на него чтобы перекидывались на внутренний SIP-томер 101? Когда пытаюсь позвонить на него - идут гудки, потом система отвечает что данный сервис запрещен для данного вызова или что не верный номер. C внутреннего на внутренний вызов могу совершать.

Думаю что я что-то настроил не верно в extensions_custom.conf

Вот содержимое extensions_custom.conf

```
[from-trunk-dongle]
exten => sms,1,Verbose(Incoming SMS from ${CALLERID(num)} ${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})})
exten => sms,n,System(echo "To: mail@mail.ru\nSubject: Incoming SMS from ${CALLERID(num)}\n\n${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DONGLENAME} - ${CALLERID(num)}: " > /var/log/asterisk/sms.txt
exten => sms,n,Set(FILE(/var/log/asterisk/sms.txt,,,a)=${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})})
exten => sms,n,System(sendmail -t < /var/log/asterisk/sms.txt)
exten => sms,n,DongleSendSMS(dongle0,+79120000000,${BASE64_DECODE(${SMS_BASE64})} - from ${CALLERID(num)})
exten => sms,n,Hangup()
exten => ussd,1,Verbose(Incoming USSD: ${USSD})
exten => ussd,n,System(echo '${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} - ${DATACARD}:${USSD}' >> /var/log/asterisk/ussd.txt)
exten => ussd,n,Hangup()
exten => _.,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle0/+${EXTEN})
exten => _.,n,Goto(from-trunk,${EXTEN},1)
exten => _.,1,Dial(SIP/101,60,mt)
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/101,,)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Посмотрите консолью, попадают ли вообще входящие через донгл звонки в этот контекст. Ну и там видно будет, куда они собственно проваливаются.

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых вариантах chan_dongle (не скажу за все, не уверен) extension и контекст, которые назначаются входящим на донгл звонкам, прописываются в файле dongle.conf:

```
context=vash-context
exten=89xxxxxxxxxx
```

Вполне возможно, что с текущей конфигурацией входящий звонок обрабатывается через "exten => ._", что пытается засылать его обратно в сотовую сеть с понятным результатом.

Поэтому: назначьте входящим звонкам конкретный exten в dongle.conf и обрабатывайте именно его в dialplan'е.

Comment: Честно говоря странно. Сделал полную перезагрузку RASPBX и заработало с текущими настройками. Правда отвалилась mysql но это уже другая причина.